# password column of a table in mysql, when moved from Linux to Windows doesn't match

Tags: java, mysql

We have a password column which stores from generated base64 hash. So when the user enters the password to login, it compares the password column in the database with the base64 of user password.  But after migrating the data (using mysql mysqldump) from Linux to Windows 7, the passwords doesn't matches. Even though the passwords from the DB and the base64 hash generated from the password entered by User seems to be same. Do we need to do any additon steps in mysql while migrating the password column  when migrating from linux to windows.

Note: When we migrate the data from linux to another linux it works, so we thought we should do unixtodos when migrating it from linux to windows. But still it fails.

We use java in the application[image]

Code used to encode password

```
try
{
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    md.update(password.getBytes());
    byte[] raw = md.digest();
    encodedPassword = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(raw);
}
```

Comment: That field is barely an MD5 hash

Comment: Also md5 is barely security against anything.

Comment: That's base64 encoded, or is that just the way that your tool shows it?

Comment: Although off topic, @PeeHaa has a good point. Even with salting, MD5 is not good enough for password hashing.

Comment: Is the hash additionally encrypted somehow?

Comment: @Steven you are right, we started with md5 but one of our developer converted to base64 i believe

Comment: @user1595858: Please tell this developer that base64 is not an encryption or hash algorithm - it only is an encoding. Base64 does not help at all when you need security.

Comment: @cyroxx what is the best we can do to make it secure then?

Comment: Can you check default charsets on both servers and dump you are using for migration? May be this one is related: bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52494

Comment: @shubhansh have checked the character set of that column in windows and linux and it is latin1

Comment: what about the files from which you are dumping. Try doing it through some MySQL GUI. e.g. SQLyog

Comment: @shubhansh i don't understand your point. The value of password is same as of source after the migration.

Comment: @cyroxx I just figure out that we do ecrypt with SHA-512 and ecode using base64. So it should be secured

Comment: @user1595858: Yes, the SHA-512 will do, although it would even be better if they were [salted](http://alistapart.com/article/web-cryptography-salted-hash-and-other-tasty-dishes#section1). Base64 is probably used for space-efficiency. Ok, enough off-topic discussion for now.

Comment: @cyroxx: base64 is used to convert array of bytes to a string

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks for your comment. Now, what can we do to solve the original problem - the unsuccessful migration from Linux to Windows?

Comment: @cyroxx: as usually - take debugger and debug everything that doesn't work as expected